# JIRA 4.0 - Add "Story Points" field to already existing issues

Tags: jira, greenhopper

We have migrated to using Greenhopper in our Jira environment.  We have a whole lot of issues where we want to get rid of the "Original Estimate" field, and start using "Story Points".

I have added the "Story Points" to the "Configure Screen" page, however it is only appearing for New issues, the field is not being added to already existing issues.

Does anyone know how to get this field added to already existing issues?

Cheers!
ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GreenHopper (Agile -> Planning Board) you will want to ensure that the Story Points field is added to your Story "issue type". Do this via Agile -> Planning Board -> Tools -> Configuration.

If you are able to upgrade to a newer version of JIRA (4.4 for instance) you will see GreenHopper provides a [project template](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GH/Configuring+your+General+Project+Settings). You can switch this over to Scrum and get Epics, Story Points, and much more set up quickly.

Thanks Ben.

Regards,
Nicholas